# Update UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've got a problem. I have this tableview and this pickerView
[image]

and this is the pickerView functions of the viewcontroller:

```
let gender = ["M","F"]

@IBOutlet weak var dataTableView: UITableView!

//pickerFuncs

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return gender[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return gender.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    print(gender[row])
}
```

How to modify the "m" in the cell with the selection of the uipicker? thanks everybody!

Comment: If the cells are dynamic create an appropriate data source model, update the model and reload the table view. If the cells are static use IBOutlets and update the cells directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable

```
var currentGender = "M"
```

Set your TableViewCell with `currentGender` like

```
cell.gender = currentGender
```

When you select a row in `UIPickerView`,

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    currentGender = gender[row]
    // Then reload your TableView row
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: rowNumber, section: 0)
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to have your M and F appear inside your pickerView. To do this you have to create a reference. This can be done through an `IBOutlet` or you can do it programmatically like so:         `let pickerView = UIPickerView()`. On a side note, I am also assuming you are only using one `pickerView` in the View Controller. If you are using multiple, set each of the pickerViews a tag. This can be done in the interface builder and programatically like so: `pickerView.tag = 1`. Then change your pickerView functions based on those tags.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a variable.
        var gender = "M"
2. Initialise again your gender variable. In this delegate method.
     func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
   gender = gender[row]
   // Then reload your TableView row
   table view.reloadData()
   }
3. Add these lines to your cellforrow_atIndexPath.
   Cell.genderIdicatorLbl.text = gender
   Note: genderIndicatorLbl is IBOutlet for your gender indicator Label